# Using ElasticSearch Shield Plugin in OSGI Environment

Tags: java, elasticsearch, osgi

I'm kind of a beginner in OSGI environment.  Currently I have integrated the java client Apache ServiceMix ElasticSearch 1.7.0_1 bundle into our code to interact with ES.  It works great.

Currently we are working on integrating the Shield plugin.  However, I don't see any related Shield plugin from Servicemix bundle.  I tried to bundle the Shield JAR from ElasticSearch repo directly under features.xml with "wrap:mvn:com.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-shield/1.3.3".  But during runtime, it throws ClassNotFoundException on any reference to com.elasticsearch.shield.xyz.

Wonder if anyone has experience or pointer on getting ElasticSearch-Shield to work under OSGI environment?

Thanks,
Frank